# Magento setup page redirect to another url

Tags: php, magento

[image]

I'm a beginner I have this screen when i go to setup of project(redirect to /setup/#/landing), i have just installed magento but not see the home page, how can i do to visualize the admin panel and the homescreen?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install Magento setup first. Please run below command from Magento root directory.

```
php bin/magento setup:install --base-url="[BASE_URL]"  --db-host="localhost" --db-name="[DB_NAME]" --db-user="[DB_USER]" --db-password="[DB_PWD]" --admin-firstname="[ADMIN_FIRSTNAME]" --admin-lastname="[ADMIN_LASTNAME]" --admin-email="[ADMIN_EMAIL]" --admin-user="[ADMIN_USERNAME]" --admin-password="[ADMIN_PASSWORD]"
```

You can check detailed steps [here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli.html)

Comment: I have just run this command and go successfully but after show nothing